# Difficulty splitting strings read from a file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I need to read input from a file, then split the word in capitals from it's definition. My trouble being that I need multiple lines from the file to be in one variable to pass it to another function. 
The file I want to read from looks like this

ACHROMATIC. An optical term applied to those telescopes in which
aberration of the rays of light, and the colours dependent thereon, are
partially corrected. (*See* APLANATIC.)

ACHRONICAL. An ancient term, signifying the rising of the heavenly
bodies at sunset, or setting at sunrise.

ACROSS THE TIDE. A ship riding across tide, with the wind in the
direction of the tide, would tend to leeward of her anchor; but with a
weather tide, or that running against the wind, if the tide be strong,
would tend to windward. A ship under sail should prefer the tack that
stems the tide, with the wind *across the stream*, when the anchor is
let go.

Right now my code splits the word from the rest, but I'm having difficulty getting the rest of the input into one variable.

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), mFile) != NULL){
    if (strlen(line) != 2){
        if (isupper(line[0]) && isupper(line[1])){
            word = strtok(line, ".");
            temp = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            len = strlen(temp);
            for (i=0; i < len; i++){
                *(defn+i) = *(temp+i);
            }
            printf("Word: %s\n", word);
        }
        else{

            temp = strtok(line, "\n");
            for (i=len; i < strlen(temp) + len; i++);
                *(defn+i) = *(temp+i-len);
            len = len + strlen(temp);
            //printf(" %s\n", temp);
        }
    }
    else{
        len = 0;
        printf("%s\n", defn);
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact format of the input file? Where are the newlines? One newline at the end of each definition and one between definitions, or one after each line of text in your example?

Comment: And what do you mean by, "I need multiple lines from the file to be in one variable to pass it to another function." What, exactly, is expected of output?

Comment: @DavidBowling I have the layout of the input file above. all caps for the word, followed by a definition. I am supposed to pass this into a hash table and need the whole definition to be passed as one, however since fgets is reading line by line the definition is getting passed part by part.

Comment: My first question is about newlines; where are they? My next question is: what do you need to pass? An array containing one definition?

Comment: I tried filling in the blanks to get this code to *compile*, but it seems wrought with warnings and errors. I think you should ask a question about some of *those warnings*, if you don't understand them. Otherwise, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidBowling One definition can span over multiple lines, so there are newlines within the definition. Then there is a full blank line in between each word/definition pair. I need to pass one string with the word, and one string with the definition for each pair.

Comment: If `defn` has sufficient capacity, you can read one definition and create a split point with `strchr`.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

//another function
void func(char *word, char *defs){
    printf("<%s>\n", word);
    if(defs){
        printf("%s", defs);
    }
}

int main(void){
    char buffer[4096], *curr = buffer;
    size_t len, buf_size = sizeof buffer;
    FILE *fp = fopen("dic.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(curr, buf_size, fp)){
        //check definition line
        if(*curr == '\n' || !isupper(*curr)){
            continue;//printf("invalid format\n");
        }
        len = strlen(curr);
        curr += len;
        buf_size -= len;
        //read rest line
        while(1){
            curr = fgets(curr, buf_size, fp);
            if(!curr || *curr == '\n'){//upto EOF or blank line
                char *word, *defs;
                char *p = strchr(buffer, '.');
                if(p)
                    *p++ = 0;
                word = buffer;
                defs = p;
                func(word, defs);
                break;
            }
            len = strlen(curr);
            curr += len;
            buf_size -= len;
            assert(buf_size >= 2 || (fprintf(stderr, "small buffer\n"), 0));
        }
        curr = buffer;
        buf_size = sizeof buffer;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to first pull a string of uppercase letters from the beginning of the line, up to the first period, then concatenate the remainder of that line with subsequent lines until a blank line is found.  Lather, rinse, repeat as needed.
While this task would be MUCH easier in Perl, if you need to do it in C, for one thing I recommend using the built-in string functions instead of constructing your own for-loops to copy the data. Perhaps something like the following:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), mFile) != NULL) {
    if (strlen(line) > 2) {
        if (isupper(line[0]) && isupper(line[1])) {
            word = strtok(line, ".");
            strcpy(defn,strtok(NULL, "\n"));
            printf("Word: %s\n", word);
        } else {
            strcat(defn,strtok(line, "\n"));
        }
    } else {
        printf("%s\n", defn);
        defn[0] = 0;
    }
}
```

When I put this in a properly structured C program, with appropriate include files, it works fine.  I personally would have approached the problem differently, but hopefully this gets you going.

Answer (score 0):

There are several areas that can be addressed. Given your example input and description, it appears your goal is to develop a function that will read and separate each word (or phrase) and associated definition, return a pointer to the collection of words/definitions, while also updating a pointer to the number of words and definitions read so that number is available back in the calling function (`main` here).

While your data suggests that the word and definition are both contained within a single line of text with the word (or phrase written in all upper-case), it is unclear whether you will have to address the case where the definition can span multiple lines (essentially causing you to potentially read multiple lines and combine them to form the complete definition.

Whenever you need to maintain relationships between multiple variables within a single object, then a `struct` is a good choice for the base data object. Using an *array of struct* allows you access to each word and its associated definition once all have been read into memory. Now your example has 3 words and definitions. (each separated by a `'\n'`). Creating an array of 3 struct to hold the data is trivial, but when reading data, like a dictionary, you rarely know exactly how many words you will have to read.

To handle this situation, a *dynamic array of structs* is a proper data structure. You essentially allocate space for some reasonable number of words/definitions, and then if you reach that limit, you simply `realloc` the array containing your data, update your limit to reflect the new size allocated, and continue on.

While you can use `strtok` to separate the word (or phrase) by looking for the first `'.'`, that is a bit of an overkill. You will need to traverse over each char anyway to check if they are all caps anyway, you may as well just iterate until you find the `'.'` and use the number for that character index to store your word and set a pointer to the next char after the `'.'`. You will begin looking for the start of the definition from there (you basically want to skip any character that is not an `[a-zA-Z]`). Once you locate the beginning of the definition, you can simply get the length of the rest of the line, and copy that as the definition (or the first part of it if the definition is contained in multiple-separate lines).

After the file is read and the pointer returned and the pointer for the number of words updated, you can then use the array of structs back in `main` as you like. Once you are done using the information, you should `free` all the memory you have allocated.

Since the size of the maximum word or phrase is generally know, the struct used provides static storage for the word. Give the definitions can vary wildly in length and are much longer, the struct simply contains a *pointer-to-char**. So you will have to allocate storage for each struct, and then allocates storage for each definition within each struct.

The following code does just that. It will take the filename to read as the first argument (or it will read from `stdin` by default if no filename is given). The code the output the words and definitions on single lines. The code is heavily commented to help you follow along and explain the logic e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {MAXW = 64, NDEF = 128}; 

typedef struct {        /* struct holding words/definitions */
    char word[MAXW],
        *def;           /* you must allocate space for def */
} defn;

defn *readdict (FILE *fp, size_t *n);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    defn *defs = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(defs = readdict (fp, &n))) { /* read words/defs into defs */
        fprintf (stderr, "readdict() error: no words read from file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("\nword: %s\n\ndefinition: %s\n", defs[i].word, defs[i].def);
        free (defs[i].def);         /* free allocated definitions */
    }
    free (defs);    /* free array of structs */

    return 0;
}

/** read word and associated definition from open file stream 'fp'
 *  into dynamic array of struct, updating pointer 'n' to contain
 *  the total number of defn structs filled.
 */
defn *readdict (FILE *fp, size_t *n)
{
    defn *defs = NULL;                     /* pointer to array of structs   */
    char buf[BUFSIZ] = "";                 /* buffer to hold each line read */
    size_t max = NDEF, haveword = 0, offset = 0;  /* allocated size & flags */

    /* allocate, initialize & validate memory to hold 'max' structs */
    if (!(defs = calloc (max, sizeof *defs))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, BUFSIZ, fp))     /* read each line of input */
    {
        if (*buf == '\n') {         /* check for blank line */
            if (haveword) (*n)++;   /* if word/def already read, increment n */
            haveword = 0;           /* reset haveword flag */
            if (*n == max) {
                void *tmp = NULL;   /* tmp ptr to realloc defs */
                if (!(tmp = realloc (defs, sizeof *defs * (max + NDEF)))) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhaused, realloc defs.\n");
                    break;
                }
                defs = tmp;     /* assign new block to defs */
                memset (defs + max, 0, NDEF * sizeof *defs); /* zero new mem */
                max += NDEF;    /* update max with current allocation size */
            }
            continue;           /* get next line */
        }

        if (haveword) {                 /* word already stored in defs[n].word */
            void *tmp = NULL;           /* tmp pointer to realloc */
            size_t dlen = strlen (buf); /* get line/buf length */
            if (buf[dlen - 1] == '\n')  /* trim '\n' from end */
                buf[--dlen] = 0;        /* realloc & validate */
            if (!(tmp = realloc (defs[*n].def, offset + dlen + 2))) {
                fprintf (stderr, 
                        "error: memory exhaused, realloc defs[%zu].def.\n", *n);
                break;
            }
            defs[*n].def = tmp;     /* assign new block, fill with definition */
            sprintf (defs[*n].def + offset, offset ? " %s" : "%s", buf);
            offset += dlen + 1;     /* update offset for rest (if required) */
        }
        else {                      /* no current word being defined */
            char *p = NULL;
            size_t i;
            for (i = 0; buf[i] && i < MAXW; i++) {   /* check first MAXW chars */
                if (buf[i] == '.') {         /* if a '.' is found, end of word */
                    size_t dlen = 0;
                    if (i + 1 == MAXW) {  /* check one char available for '\0' */
                        fprintf (stderr, 
                                 "error: 'word' exceeds MAXW, skipping.\n");
                        goto next;
                    }
                    strncpy (defs[*n].word, buf, i); /* copy i chars to .word  */
                    haveword = 1;                    /* set haveword flag      */
                    p = buf + i + 1;    /* set p to next char in buf after '.' */
                    while (*p && (*p == ' ' || *p < 'A' ||   /* find def start */
                        ('Z' < *p && *p < 'a') || 'z' < *p))
                        p++;                    /* increment p and check again */
                    if ((dlen = strlen (p))) {  /* get definition length */
                        if (p[dlen - 1] == '\n') /* trim trailing '\n' */
                            p[--dlen] = 0;
                        if (!(defs[*n].def = malloc (dlen + 1))) { /* allocate */
                            fprintf (stderr, 
                                     "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
                            goto done;            /* bail if allocation failed */
                        }
                        strcpy (defs[*n].def, p);   /* copy definition to .def */
                        offset = dlen;         /* set offset in .def buf to be */
                    }                          /* used if def continues on a   */
                    break;                     /* new or separae line */
                }               /* check word is all upper-case or a ' ' */ 
                else if (buf[i] != ' ' && (buf[i] < 'A' || 'Z' < buf[i]))
                    break;
            }
        }
        next:;
    }
    done:;

    if (haveword) (*n)++;   /* account for last word/definition */

    return defs;            /* return pointer to array of struct */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/dict_read <dat/dict.txt

word: ACHROMATIC

definition: An optical term applied to those telescopes in which 
aberration of the rays of light, and the colours dependent thereon, 
are partially corrected. (See APLANATIC.)

word: ACHRONICAL

definition: An ancient term, signifying the rising of the heavenly 
bodies at sunset, or setting at sunrise.

word: ACROSS THE TIDE

definition: A ship riding across tide, with the wind in the direction 
of the tide, would tend to leeward of her anchor; but with a weather tide, 
or that running against the wind, if the tide be strong, would tend to 
windward. A ship under sail should prefer the tack that stems the tide, 
with the wind across the stream, when the anchor is let go.
```

(line breaks were manually inserted to keep the results tidy here).

**Memory Use/Error Check**

You should also run any code that dynamically allocates memory though a memory use and error checking program like `valgrind` on linux. Just run the code though it and confirm you free all memory you allocate and that there are no memory errors, e.g.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/dict_read <dat/dict.txt
==31380== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31380== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31380== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31380== Command: ./bin/dict_read
==31380==

word: ACHROMATIC

<snip output>
==31380==
==31380== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31380==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31380==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 9,811 bytes allocated
==31380==
==31380== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31380==
==31380== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31380== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.